# Hide tabs using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook and would like, once the user has selected an option from a drop down, to hide several other worksheets. Code is currently -

```
Sub select_role()

Dim role As String

role = Sheet3.Cells(11, "F").Value

Select Case role
Case "Project Manager"
Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet6.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet7.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet8.Visible = xlSheetHidden

Case "Business Analyst"
Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet6.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet7.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet8.Visible = xlSheetHidden

Case "Developer"
Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet6.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet8.Visible = xlSheetHidden

Case "Architect"
Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet6.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet7.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetHidden

Case "Payments"
Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet6.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet7.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet8.Visible = xlSheetHidden

Case "New Role"
Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet6.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet7.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet8.Visible = xlSheetHidden

End Select

End Sub
```

However as I debug it it gets into one of the cases correctly and then as it moves from the first sheet to the second in the list I get an Run-time error '1004'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Sheet11` is almost always the second sheet to be hidden. Is it protected?

Comment: On which line do you get the run-time error? Did you check if all sheets exist? It seems the sub is only hiding and not showing any sheets. Maybe the sheet is already hidden? Is the workbook (or any of the sheets) protected?

Comment: Does it happen with New Role as well, that's the only one that doesn't have sheet11 as the second value

Comment: Thank you everyone. Adam was correct, Sheet11 was protected. Unfortunately I cannot see a way to accept a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd encourage you to use this pattern. It is easier to maintain and less verbose:

```
Sub Select_Role()
    Dim role As String, shts(), sht As Integer

    role = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("F11")

    Select Case role
        Case "Project Manager"
            shts = Array(10, 11, 4, 6, 7, 8)
        Case "Business Analyst"
            shts = Array(10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8)
        Case "Developer"
            shts = Array(10, 11, 4, 6, 5, 8)
        Case "Architect"
            shts = Array(10, 11, 4, 6)
        Case "New Role"
            shts = Array(10, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8)
    End Select

    For sht = 0 To UBound(shts)
        If Worksheets("Sheet" & shts(sht)).Visible Then
            Worksheets("Sheet" & shts(sht)).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next sht

End Sub
```

- Each `Array` holds the sheet references you want to hide. They can be sheet names or indexes.
- You can easily update each array to suit your needs as well as add and delete new cases
- The loop first checks whether the sheet is visible or not but you could add more conditions e.g. `protected`, `xlVeryHidden` etc...

Comment: Thanks Alex, I have tried your solution however it throws a subscript out of range error. Run-time error '9' on the If then statement.

Comment: Hmmm. You don't have excel array index set to `1` do you as a global option? It worked for me in testing.